# Adding html to t() in Drupal 6 template.php?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views, drupal-themes

Hi I am trying to add html to the "t('Older Posts')" and "t('Newer Posts')" Is this possible ? I can figure it out ????
I am in a Drupal 6 template.php file.

This is the code I am trying to add as html -

```
 <a href="" class="action"><span>Newer Posts</span></a>
 <a href="" class="action back"><span>Older Posts</span></a>
```

I need to replace the above in these spots located in the full function below ?

```
 t('Older Posts')
 t('Newer Posts')
```

I want to create something like this

```
 t('<a href="" class="action back"><span>Older Posts</span></a>')
 t('<a href="" class="action"><span>Newer Posts</span></a>')
```

Full Function

```
 function theme_views_mini_pager($tags = array(), $limit = 10, 
 $element = 0,  $parameters = array(), $quantity = 9) {      
 global $pager_page_array, $pager_total;

 // Calculate various markers within this pager piece:
 // Middle is used to "center" pages around the current page.
 $pager_middle = ceil($quantity / 2);
 // current is the page we are currently paged to
 $pager_current = $pager_page_array[$element] + 1;
 // max is the maximum page number
 $pager_max = $pager_total[$element];
 // End of marker calculations.


$li_previous = theme('pager_previous', (isset($tags[1]) ? $tags[1] : 
t('Older Posts')), $limit, $element, 1, $parameters);
 if (empty($li_previous)) {
$li_previous = "&nbsp;";
}

$li_next = theme('pager_next', (isset($tags[3]) ? $tags[3] : t('Newer Posts')), 
$limit,$element, 1, $parameters);
if (empty($li_next)) {
$li_next = "&nbsp;";
}

if ($pager_total[$element] > 5) {
$items[] = array(
  'class' => 'action back pager-previous',
  'data' => $li_previous,
);

$items[] = array(
  'class' => 'action pager-next',
  'data' => $li_next,
);
return theme('item_list', $items, NULL, 'ul', array('class' => 'pager'));
}
}
```

I am trying to figure out if this is possible I have tried many things and nothing has worked yet.

Comment: This question is related to **http://drupal.stackexchange.com/**

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$link = '<a href="" class="action back"><span>' . t('Older Posts') . '</span></a>';
```

OR

```
$link = t('!link_startOlder Posts!link_end', array(
  '!link_start' => '<a href="" class="action back"><span>',
  '!link_end' => '</span></a>',
));
```